# cocos2d background image dimmensions

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to get started with cocos2d by creating an app with a background image.  It's not a texture, just a straight image.

I add the background using:

```
    CCSprite* background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"paris.png"];
    background.tag = 1;
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self addChild:background z:0];
```

The image is 960x640 but when I run it in the iPhone 5 simulator I only see a small part of the image.  It's like it's too large for the screen.  I was under the impression I would need 960x640.  Is this not accurate?  What resolution should my image be?

I've tried with and without the anchorPoint being set.  Without the anchor I see a smushed image on 1/2 the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn about retina display in cocos2d:  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d

Make an image with 480x320 with name paris.png...

Rename your current image as paris-hd.png...

Enable Retina Display in app delegate.. And you are done.. Hope this helps.. :)